# Crystal Report - Suppressing footer until last page - creates empty white space on other pages

Tags: crystal-reports, reporting, footer, suppression

I've made a new crystal report.
I have some terms and conditions and a place for signature on my report footer. I have managed to suppress my report footer to only show on last page, I have used this within Section Expert

```
TotalPageCount <> Pagenumber
```

It works well and only shows on last page however on all other pages other than last I now have a lot of blank space that I could re-utilize and in effect cut number of report pages. Can someone recommend a setting that I might be missing or piece of code to do that please.

Adding image for reference :

[image]

Comment: The report footer is supposed to show only on the last page (no suppres formula is needed). Unless it is a subreport. Are you using page footer? If so, try to move the content from page footer to the report footer. Anyway, I would expect that the other sections would adjust themselves to fill the available space. Is there any chance that you are supressing some object inside the footer instead of the footer section? Or maybe the other section has a fixed size...

Comment: @heringer it was as simple as that. I've put it into page footer rather than report footer! Thanks so much!

Comment: @heringer I also put page footer. But does not working. Empty white spaces remain on other pages.